# Get a random string position with a surrounding pattern context

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient python solution to the following problem. I have a DNA sequence and would like to pick a random position in the string that satisfies the middle position of a certain triplet pattern. For example if the DNA string was "ACTGTGACTACTGGGGG", and the triple was "ACT", I would like to return, at random, one of positions 1, 7, 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the indices for the substring matches using `re.finditer`, then use `random.choice` to select one of those.

```
>>> import re
>>> import random
>>> s = 'ACTGTGACTACTGGGGG'
>>> f = 'ACT'
>>> indices = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(f, s)]
>>> random.choice(indices)
0
>>> random.choice(indices)
9
```

Note that indices in Python are 0-based so in your example the valid starting locations are `0`, `6`, and `9`.